# How to use SSL on certain pages on JSF 2.2?

Tags: jsf, ssl

I am trying to use SSL on a login page and on a register. Both pages are on my /public folder.
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958881/how-to-force-only-one-page-to-open-with-ssl) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513661/https-on-jsf-2-for-protected-resources-and-login). One says that I can and one that I can not. I tried to use the second one but I wasn't able to secure my pages. I tried to use different url-patterns but ether it didn't work or I got

```
HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied
```

and

```
Info:   JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(PropertyWS/PropertyWS)- permission(("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/PropertyWS/public/index.xhtml" "GET"))
Info:   JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(PropertyWS/PropertyWS)- permission(("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "/PropertyWS/public/index.xhtml" "GET:CONFIDENTIAL"))
```

So, to sum up, is this possible or not? And how (what to put in the url-patterns)?

Comment: Don't think that's a JSF related question, but a server-related one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5304358/1199132

Comment: No it is not. Please look at my links and you will see it for yourself.